# Problems getting connected to a secure websocket in go

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm having some troubles doing this exact [connection](https://github.com/cryptoqween/cryptoqween.github.io/blob/master/streamer/current/stream.js#L4-L17) in go-lang.

Thus far, I've done:

```golang
u := url.URL{Scheme: "wss", Host: "streamer.cryptocompare.com"}

var dialer *websocket.Dialer
conn, _, err := dialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
l.Log(err)

msg, err := json.Marshal(Message{"SubAdd", map[string]interface{}{"subs": []string{"5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD"}}})
l.Log(err)

err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msg)
fmt.Println(err.Error())
l.Log(err)
```

I'm still learning about websockets, and how to use them.

**Edit:** This is the error, I'm getting:

```sh
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x718937]

goroutine 22 [running]:
github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Conn).WriteMessage(0x0, 0x1, 0xc420248020, 0x36, 0x40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/avl/go/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket/conn.go:734 +0x37
main.SetupSockets(0xc420058370)
    /home/avl/Dropbox/Development/mixed/server/crypto.go:55 +0x378
created by main.main
    /home/avl/Dropbox/Development/mixed/server/main.go:21 +0x9a
exit status 2
```

**Edit 2:** Line 55 in crypto.go corresponds to this `msg, err := json.Marshal(Message{"SubAdd", map[string]interface{}{"subs": []string{"5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD"}}})`

Comment: The second return value from dialer.Dial is the response form the server. I suggest printing the response status and body to see what might be wrong. Also, the service uses socket.io. You will need to use or implement whatever socket.io adds above the websocket protocol.

Comment: Trying, but no luck. The response is nil

Comment: `Unexpected EOF`

Comment: That error indicates that the server is closing the connection without writing an HTTP response.  Perhaps the server is closing the connection because the request is invalid.

Comment: Figured. But thanks! Wrote them already!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you get error while `conn, _, err := dialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)`

> unexpected EOF

You have to handle this error, it occurs because of response of the server:

https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/client.go#L282

```
resp, err := http.ReadResponse(conn.br, req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, nil, err
}
```

After that error `WriteMessage` method doesn't make sense.

Comment: Though, I've updated my question. Can you explain why I'm getting an EOF?

Comment: There are problems with your server,
```u := url.URL{Scheme: "wss", Host: "echo.websocket.org"}``` works fine.